# How to set encoder to PHP PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm using Php5.6.2 And postgres as database connection.
postgres is set to UTF-8

i was try to select db, but it return error "SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: `7 ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "EUC_JP": 0xe58e"`

```
$this->db = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test","cadusr","cadpass");
```

Some query is working successfully, but some are not.
I expect that maybe the fail queries are include Japanese.

Can i get some teaching? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry self answer as soon as ask.

Before asking, I found only English web with error message.

But i could find after asking easily Japanese web with keyword PHP PDO pgsql.
So, This is solution.

Add this line of code below in host after ip.

```
options='--client_encoding=UTF8'

new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost  options='--client_encoding=UTF8';dbname=test","cadusr","cadpass");
```

Hope that help you.